# How to merge shapefiles following a particular order?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, shapefile

I have a dataset containing 171 shapefiles, their names as "shp0_0" to "shp0_171". I need to merge them into a single shapefile. When I use the merge tool and load all the .shp from the folder, it gives me random order, they are not listed by the filename order.

I need the output attribute table's FIDs to correspond with the input shapefiles: shp1 to be in the 1st row and have FID 0, shp2 to be in the 2nd row and have FID 1 and so on.

Is there a way to list all shapefiles to be merged numerically sorted by filename?

I work in arcmap 10.3 (using arcpy).

Comment: What GIS software are you using?

Comment: It's not a great idea to use the FID for this purpose as you don't generally have any control over them. A better solution would be to add and populate a new field called filenum or rownum to each of the 171 shapefiles, then merge.

Comment: I just wanted to emphasize @Alexander 's comment (more than I did by upvoting it): you should absolutely NOT USE FIDs as an ID field. Those numbers can and do change when a shapefile is edited. You should add a dedicated field for ID values. That would also make this question unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, in the end I had to resort to Alexander's suggestion because I needed to do few more tasks with the shapefiles. Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will list the shapefiles, sort by number and merge. I dont know if it will give you the results you want though, you will have to try:

```
import arcpy

shapefile_folder = r'C:\folder' #Change to your folder containing the shapefiles
arcpy.env.workspace = shapefile_folder
shapelist = sorted(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(), key = lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0][5:]))

arcpy.Merge_management(inputs=shapelist, output='Shapefiles_merge.shp')
```

The code can be executed in the [Python window](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/executing-tools/what-is-the-python-window-.htm).

Comment: I tried to run the script and it failed saying:

Runtime error 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<string>", line 5, in <module>
  File "<string>", line 5, in <lambda>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '0_1'


The real filenames of the shapefiles are from "GPL0.shp" to "GPL0_170.shp"

Comment: Rename GPL0 to GPL0_0 and try again, i have changed the code

Comment: This time it worked perfectly. Thank you very much.
I'd like to learn from this, what does this line do? shapelist = sorted(arcpy.ListFeatureClasses(), key = lambda x: int(x.split('.')[0][5:]))
Especially after key =

Comment: Nice! The sorting of the shapefile list is done using a lambda function. See for example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8966538/syntax-behind-sortedkey-lambda

Comment: Without it it would sort the shapefiles alphabetical and not by the numbers